# Checkbox and search query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, search, codeigniter

My page is coded in PHP/codeigniter and I have a form with some checkboxes in it. When I select a few checkboxes and submit the form, I pass the checkbox values to the controller, which then decides if a checkbox is checked, implodes all the checked checkbox values into an array and passes to the url using uri->assoc_to_uri($array). This is how I coded my filters for a search engine (any better way?). Now when I redisplay the form with the checkboxes again, I want the checkboxes previously checked to be checked again. How can I do this?

My initial idea is to do a uri_>uri_to_assoc(#), find the value of the relevant key (ie. 1.2.3) then explode to an array $arr and something like the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="price_range_4" value="<?php if($arr[4] != '') echo 'selected'; ?>">
```

Is there a faster/better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the Session Class and pass an array to set_flashdata(), then retrieve it on the search results page to check the checkboxes?

Comment: Just note that flashdata expires after the next request, normal session data should be OK.

Comment: Yeah the reason I said flashdata was because I just thought they are going to probably leave after one search of search again, both ways work fine.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Darren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032794/checkbox-and-search-query-in-codeigniter/6034850#6034850) you have another HTML problem:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="price_range_4" value="<?php if($arr[4] != '') echo 'selected'; ?>">
```

It's not the `value` you want to change, it's the `checked` attribute. Something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="price_range_4" value="my_value"<?php if ($should_be_checked) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> />
```

If you're using the [Form helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html), you can use the `form_checkbox()` function to make this a bit cleaner:

Example:

```
echo form_checkbox('price_range_4', 'my_value', $should_be_checked);
```

Of course `$should_be_checked` will be whatever way you decide to define it, either with session data, $_POST data, or another way.